# Extracting from a file - permission denied

Tags: lua, permission-denied

I have tried to extract from an extension .w3speech, and found a set of lua codes that seem to be working, however, I followed the instruction but got "permission denied." The code writer isn't responding ... so I just hope that someone would look over the problem and provide some directions. Thanks you.

Inspect_w3speech.lua

```
require("mod_binary_reader")
require("mod_w3strings")

local in_file = assert(arg[1], "\n\nno input\n")
local out_dir = arg[2] or "."
local debug = arg[3] or false

local r = BinaryReader
r:open(in_file)
```

mod_binary_reader.lua

```
assert(_VERSION == "Lua 5.3")

BinaryReader = {
    f_handle = nil,`
    f_size = 0
}

function BinaryReader:open(fullpath)
    self.f_handle = assert(io.open(fullpath, "rb"))
    self.f_size = self.f_handle:seek("end")
    assert(-1 ~= self.f_size, "your Lua doesn't support files larger than 2 Gb")
    self.f_handle:seek("set")
end
```

As instructed, I wrote a simple bat file to read inspect_w3speech.lua as following.

```
a:\vid_inwork\work\lua.exe inspect_w3speech.lua a:\vid_inwork\work a:\vid_inwork\work\out
```

But, it gave the following.

```
a:\vid_inwork\work\lua.exe: a:\vid_inwork\work\mod_binary_reader.lua:9: a:\vid_inwork\work: Permission Denied
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'assert'
a:\vid_inwork\work\mod_binary_reader.lua:9: in method 'open'
inspect_w3speech.lua:9: in maind chunk
[C]: in ?
```

It seems to be stuck at where inspect_w3speech.lua calls mod_binary_reader.lua, and wonder why.

Here is the link to the complete lua files and a sample .w3speech file.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByIVyOBFNEN4fl9ic2ltdDFfckJnLVdQV1VnQmJ4TUxodmhwblY3dEt2UTIyWGFfbU1FeG8&usp=sharing

Comment: Is `a:\vid_inwork\work` the file to work with? Because it looks like a directory and that's not right.

Comment: Yes ... that's where all the lua files are ... The instruction says to type ... lua inspect_w3speech.lua path_to.w3speech [output_dir [debug]] ... upon research I learned that I should type that way, but if it's my ignorance of comprehending the simple instruction and not the code, then I'd be happy to correct that.

Comment: Yes, `path_to.w3speech` not `path to directory of .w3speech files`. Look at the code. It runs `io.open` on the first argument so it needs to be a file.

Comment: Thank you so much! But where should I put the path directory to .w3speech files? The bat file gave me ... mod_binary_reader.lua:9: path_to_w3speech: no such file or directory ... Should I search mod_binary_reader.lua to add or change the directory?

Comment: `path_to.w3speech` is a placeholder. You use the path to the `.w3speech` file you want the script to operate on. `a:\vid_inwork\work\some_file.w3speech` or whatever.

Comment: That's so strange ... I have .w3speech file in the same directory as all the other lua files as well as the simple bat file I wrote ... but still the bat file gave me "mod_binary_reader.lua:9: pathe_to.w3peech: no such file or directory"

Comment: Is your file named `pathe_to.w3speech` or something else? You have to actually use the name of your actual file on the command line.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!! I feel sooooooo stupid now. Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! It worked ... Seriously, I can't thank you enough. I spent sooo much time past few days trying to figure it out, left sos on so many other sites, but no response. This site is THE BEST. And thank you so much for this swift rescue.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the script with a directory as the first argument

```
a:\vid_inwork\work\lua.exe inspect_w3speech.lua a:\vid_inwork\work a:\vid_inwork\work\out
```

but it expects a filename.

So give it the path to the file you want to operate on.

```
a:\vid_inwork\work\lua.exe inspect_w3speech.lua a:\vid_inwork\work\some_file.w3speech a:\vid_inwork\work\out
```